# PHP to work out which of the following add up to final figure

Tags: php, binary

I have a set of pre determined values:

```
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000
100000000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000000000000000
100000000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000000000000
100000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000000000
100000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000000
100000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000000
100000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000
1000000000000000000000
100000000000000000000
10000000000000000000
1000000000000000000
100000000000000000
10000000000000000
1000000000000000
100000000000000
10000000000000
1000000000000
100000000000
10000000000
1000000000
100000000
10000000
1000000
100000
10000
1000
100
10
1
```

and im given another value:

```
1000000100100000000000000000000000
```

How do i work out what combination of binary values add up to the one im given?

note, the values sometimes are ony 1 of the predefined values, sometimes it can be all of them.

it looks simple to me, but im drawing blanks!

cheers!

for those who want to see my attempt so far.. here u go

```
.....



  $DBH = new PDO("dblib:host=$myServer;dbname=$SystemDB", $myUser, $myPass);
  $DBH1 = new PDO("dblib:host=$myServer;dbname=$TaxiHistoryDB", $myUser, $myPass);


  $sth = $DBH->prepare("SELECT dbo.Conditions.Name, dbo.Conditions.ConditionValue FROM dbo.Conditions Where dbo.Conditions.ConditionID > 0");
  $sth->execute();

  $result = $sth->fetchAll();
  print_r($result);
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";
  $result = array_reverse($result);
  $STH1 = $DBH1->query("SELECT dbo.tblBooking.Conditions FROM dbo.tblBooking WHERE dbo.tblBooking.BookingID = '36661447'");

  $STH1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);

  while($row1 = $STH1->fetch()){
     $condition = $row1->Conditions;
     echo $condition;
     echo "<br>";
     echo base_convert($condition, 10, 2);
     echo "<br>";
     $value = $result['ConditionValue'];
     echo $value;
     foreach($result as $array) {

         $value = $array['ConditionValue']; 
         $binaryCondition = base_convert($condition, 10, 2);
         $binaryValue = base_convert($value, 10, 2);
         echo "<br>";
         echo $binaryValue;

       }//end foreach
    }//end while
```

Comment: Is this your homework?  You need to show what you've attempted if you expect anyone to help you.

Comment: ive given it a go.. but i keep having issues with 32bit processing. @Daedalus

Comment: Can we see the code of that `Go`?

Comment: That `Go` is down the bottom in the comments to my answer. I think it consisted of looking at the number and seeing where the 1's were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to give you an answer and not explain it since it doesn't look like you've even tried!  If this is homework, you've been given it for a reason.

```
$possible_bits = array(
'1000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
'100000000000000000000000000000000000000',
'10000000000000000000000000000000000000',
'1000000000000000000000000000000000000',
'100000000000000000000000000000000000',
'10000000000000000000000000000000000',
'1000000000000000000000000000000000',
'100000000000000000000000000000000',
'10000000000000000000000000000000',
'1000000000000000000000000000000',
'100000000000000000000000000000',
'10000000000000000000000000000',
'1000000000000000000000000000',
'100000000000000000000000000',
'10000000000000000000000000',
'1000000000000000000000000',
'100000000000000000000000',
'10000000000000000000000',
'1000000000000000000000',
'100000000000000000000',
'10000000000000000000',
'1000000000000000000',
'100000000000000000',
'10000000000000000',
'1000000000000000',
'100000000000000',
'10000000000000',
'1000000000000',
'100000000000',
'10000000000',
'1000000000',
'100000000',
'10000000',
'1000000',
'100000',
'10000',
'1000',
'100',
'10',
'1');

$test_number = '1000000100100000000000000000000000';
$test_number_lsb = bindec(substr($test_number, -32));
$test_number_msb = bindec(substr_replace($test_number, '', -33));

foreach(array_reverse($possible_bits) as $bit => $bit_value){
    $dec_value_lsb = bindec(substr($bit_value, -32));
    $dec_value_msb = bindec(substr_replace($bit_value, '', -33));    
    if($test_number_lsb & $dec_value_lsb || $test_number_msb & $dec_value_msb)
        echo $bit."\n";
}
```

I've updated it to chunk in to 32-bit

Comment: I had essentially done this already. i know the answer is:

100000000000000000000000, 
1000000000000000000000000000000000,
100000000000000000000000000,

I understand what your answer is.. but it doesnt give me the results. 

i think its an issue of 32bit vs 64bit.

Comment: Update your question with what you had - you should have done this in the first place.

Comment: It should be *VERY* clear in my answer how to get the information you need.  You're barking up the wrong tree currently..

Comment: your code gives me "23 26" as the result. i dont see how this could be right???

Comment: Because it's echoing the bit position of the matching bit.  There are other things in that loop that you can echo if that's not what you want.

Comment: but the "test_number" is made up of 3 of the "possible_bits" not 2 of them, essentially it should read, 24, 27, 34 (array position) @calcinai

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37621/discussion-between-mike-and-calcinai)

Comment: When I run it, I get 23,26 and 33.  If I change what it echoes, I get 100000000000000000000000,100000000000000000000000000 and 1000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: i still feel that the 32 bit limitation of the machine i'm working on is giving me the drama. is there a long way that i could do this? because when i do echo decbin(549755813888); i get: 1111111111111111111111111111111, when it should be 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000. which indicates to me that its a 32 bit limitation. @calcinai

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

```
<?php

$test = bindec(1000000100100000000000000000000000);

for ($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++)
    if (bindec($bit = pow(10, $i)) & $test)
        echo $bit . "\n";
```

Here's a 32 bit version: http://codepad.org/nf545W2J